# What is the easiest way to execute git commands in the work tree when it is separate from git repo

Tags: git, deployment

I have bare git repo at:

```
/home/git/mysite_com.git
```

On each push to this repo, the post-receive hook does:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite.com/live/www git checkout -f master
```

Obviously, when i go to:

```
cd /var/www/mysite.com/live/www
```

and try any git command,it says:

```
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I found a solution:

```
cd /var/www/mysite.com/live/www 
export GIT_DIR=/home/git/mysite_com.git
export GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www/mysite.com/live/www
```

Is there a simpler way to do this? I have to copy & paste this commands over and over, every time i need to use the git commands.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `core.worktree` option in the `git repo`:

```
$ git config core.worktree /var/www/mysite.com/live/www
```

And then use the `--git-dir` option to `git` when you're in the worktree:

```
$ git --git-dir=/home/git/mysite_com.git <subcommand>
```

Comment: i get the message

`fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`